# Travelling with a passport that will expire in less than 6 months

Tags: indonesia, residency

I am an Australian permanent resident and I have booked a flight to Indonesia in November and by November, I will only have 5 months left before my passport expires. Is it fine to travel with it and for me to come back to Australia, considering I have permanent residency?

Comment: Why not take the opportunity to renew your passport in the next two months and avoid any potential issues?

Comment: According to this site https://visalink.com.au/indonesia-visa and a couple of others I searched eg https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/indonesia/entry-requirements, to enter Indonesia your passport must be valid for a minimum of 6 months after the date of departure from Indonesia.

Comment: @Traveller I suspect the OP is an Indonesian national, in which case that would not apply, but it would be helpful if they can confirm.

Comment: Which country issued your passport?

Comment: The answer depends on whether you are traveling with an Indonesian passport .  I have voted to close this question as "unclear what you are asking"; if you can clarify your nationality, I will remove the close vote.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the similar issue as well as I am Indonesian citizen residing in Germany. But from the immigration part they only asked that whether my passport will be renewed and where will it be extended as it is valid less than 6 months so hopefully it should be fine. The concern is now that to ensure the country you are residing should also be fine with your passport is valid less than 6 moths, but as long as you have valid visa in the residing country it should be fine.